# Raise user error if contract don't have charges

Tags: odoo, odoo-9, odoo-10

While Creating Contract if a contract does n't have any contract_lines then Contract should not be created. in case a contract is created and while editing all contract_lines has to be deleted then the contract should not be updated and raise user error. I resolved the first condition but don't know how to solve 2nd condition. Here is my code. Thanks.

```
@api.model
def create(self, vals):
    if len(vals['contract_lines']) == 0:
        raise UserError(_("Without Charges, Contract should not be saved"))
    return super(transport, self).create(vals)
```

i'm applying same methodalogie on write,update method it's not working. it's not raising any user error also.

Answer (score 1):

You need to manage one python constraints. Please have a look inside brief view on the Odoo constraints. [How to make a constraint on a fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44161950/how-to-make-a-constraint-on-a-fields/44181171#44181171)

Your solution is :

```
@api.constrains('contract_lines')
def _check_contract_lines(self):
    if len(self.contract_lines) == 0:
        raise UserError(_("Without Charges, Contract should not be saved"))
```

When you perform any operation like create, Write or unlink, This constraint is fire and you will achieve your goal.

Comment: There would be no `vals` passed into this constraint, though are there? I like this solution but wouldn't it be `self.contract_lines`?

Answer (score 0):

The `create` method is run whenever the record is saved for the first time. Any subsequent saves to the record are processed through the `write` method, so you'll want to extend it as well.

```
# Note the API call is multi, not model
@api.multi
def write(self, vals):
    # I'm not sure if the update is passed through self or vals,
    # so you may need to test this a bit.
    if not self.contract_lines or len(vals['contract_lines']) == 0:
        raise UserError(_("Without Charges, Contract should not be saved"))
    return super(transport, self).write(vals)
```